# Is it possible to figure out what is the nth percentile of a non-parametric distribution base on a few summary statistics

Tags: nonparametric

I am working on a problem where I need to reliably measure the nth percentile of a non-parametric distribution without having to use all the data. Ideally, I was wondering if it is possible to do this like the case with a parametric distribution like Gaussian, where all you need for Gaussian is the mean and variance?

Comment: Let's try this in reverse. My mean is 100 and my SD is 50. What's my 90th percentile? You need some assumptions to get anywhere.

Comment: What do you intend by "nonparametric distribution"? Do you just mean "non-normal" (which isn't what *nonparametric* means at all) or do you mean to talk about some nonparametric estimator of a density, like a kernel density estimate?

Comment: @Glen_b when I said "nonparametric", I meant something that's not like normal, exponential, poisson distribution etc. Ie. not distributions that could be uniquely defined with mean and standard deviation (for the case of normal), rate (for the case of exponential / poisson). I want a way that I could reliably measure the nth percentile of non-parametric distribution without utilizing all the data.

Comment: So you mean something like "has an unspecified distribution" or "has a distribution I couldn't easily identify"? (The phrase "nonparametric distribution" is somewhat problematic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is by fitting some known distribution to the data, then calculating the quantiles on that distribution. In finance, for instance, the popular choices are the Gaussian and Student-t distribution. There's an area of financial risk management which has a similar problem to yours it's called value-at-risk (VaR). VaR is basically a quantile.

So, in this application Johnson SU distribution is a popular choice. You fit it to the data by matching first three or four moments, then get the quantile estimation from the fitted distribution, see [this paper](http://zoonek.free.fr/blosxom/Finance/2007-10-28_Articles.pdf) for example.

UPDATE
[Here](http://www.economia.uniroma2.it/conference/Public/1/Paper/111.pdf)'s a link to a paper that describes how to fit Johnson SU distribution to the data, see p.10. The algorithm was first proposed in paper, which is behind the paywall, unfortunately: "An algorithm to determine the parameters of SU -curves in the johnson system of probabillity distributions by moment matching", Hans J.H. Tuenter

Another popular method for a similar problem is called [Cornish-Fisher expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornish%E2%80%93Fisher_expansion), which is also popular in financial industry to calculate VaR. You may find it easier to use than Johnson SU. [Here's](http://www.carolalexander.org/publish/download/JournalArticles/PDFs/IRFA_GARCH.pdf) a paper describing these and similar approaches for VaR.

Comment: Estimation of Johnson distributions by moments is often poor. Further, the bounds that the first few moments put on tail quantiles are quite weak, so the two together may not be as useful as we might hope.

Comment: I did some readings on this and it does look like something that I need. However, I couldn't find the exact form of the estimators for the four parameters used to define the Johnson SU Distribution. I was wondering if there is a closed form for these estimators?

Comment: @syang, I added references to details of application

Comment: See **1**. D. Hill, R. Hill, and R. L. Holder (1976), Algorithm AS 99. Fitting Johnson curves by moments, Appl. Statist.,25, No. 2, 180-189., $\:$

**2** I. D. Hill, (1976),  Algorithm AS 100. Normal-Johnson and Johnson-normal transformations, Appl. Statist.,25, No. 2, 190-192. $\:$ **3** I. D. Hill and R. E. Wheeler (1981),  
"Statistical Algorithms: Remark AS R33: A Remark on Algorithms AS 99: Fitting Johnson Curves by Moments and AS 100: Normal-Johnson and Johnson-Normal Transformations."  
 *Appl. Statist.*, **30**, No.1, p106
 $\:$

Comment: **4** Wheeler, R.E. (1980). Quantile estimators of Johnson curve parameters.
Biometrika.
67-3  
725-728 .....     Fitting by both moments and quantiles are available in a couple of R packages, by the way.

Comment: @Aksakal I was wondering if there is something similar to this, but for Johnson SL instead of Johnson SU? The reason why I am asking this is that the distribution of the data I am dealing with is strictly positive

Comment: @syang, I haven't seen Johnson SL used for this purpose, which doesn't necessarily mean that it can't be, of course. I wouldn't overthink this approach, once you get into extreme tails of quantiles, all methods become questionable.

Answer (score 1):

Let us treat the larger set (whose quantile you want to estimate by a smaller sample) as the population.

You can estimate population quantiles by sample quantiles. This will generally work well except for extreme quantiles.

Draw a *random* sample from your population (the large set). Compute the quantile of your sample (e.g. a sample median for a population median). Use that as an estimate of the quantile you seek. This doesn't rely on any specific distributional assumptions.

You can even use other sample quantiles to obtain a non-parametric interval for the population quantile (via a binomial argument).